# MPEG1 to MPEG4?

Tags: iphone

How to convert thro objective-C the MPEG1 to MPEG4? Is there any application that does, so that i can add to my app and test?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you don't want to do video re-encoding on an iPhone... talk about a battery suck...

Comment: Plesae suggest some way, this is something which am struggling.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh.

You could use `mencoder` to do it, but I don't suggest it. MPEG-1 is *very* different from MPEG-4. There's nothing that even approaches a good way to convert without taking a significant quality hit in the transcode.

Comment: Can it be done at source code level, as i can't have the user to download software or anything, everything should be done at source level.Thanks.

Comment: What? I'm not even sure what you're asking. Your question doesn't make sense. "Source code level" makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: The video path is coming from DB, each user will play a video on his iphone, so the video path that is stored is in MPEG1 format, to play in iphone it has to be converted to MPEG4, while the play happens from the source code, is there an option to do this conversion at the source code level from objective-c? Does this makes sense?